# XML::Simple output style

Tags: xml, perl

i need to edit a xml file wihich contains lines like:

```
<language name="en_US" title="sprint" subtitle="" url="sprint/en_US/index.html">
```

My perl script with XML::Simple is working fine expect i'n not able to have the output in exact this format. I get:

```
<language>
  <name>en_US</name>
  <subtitle>My new subtitle</subtitle>
  <title>sprint</title>
  <url>sprint/en_US/index.html</url>
</language>
```

In principle this is fine, but here the output files are comared with the input files using diff. Can i force XML::Simple to use the same output style like the input style?
My code is:
    use XML::Simple;

```
my $xml = XMLin(
  'a.xml',
  KeepRoot => 1,
  ForceArray => 1,
);

# editing xml

XMLout(
  $xml,
  KeepRoot => 1,
  NoAttr => 1,
  OutputFile => 'b.xml',
);
```

Thx

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple. XML::Simple is for simple XML and there is no such thing. Use XML::Trig instead. http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-3/

Comment: What's your target output?

Comment: @Sobrique — See the first code block in the question

Comment: Sorry, yes - I mean what's the transform you're trying to do here? E.g. input vs. output. Stripping attributes?

Comment: I would also note - using `diff` to validate XML is asking for pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egrantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) lies. It isn't, it's for simple XML. From it's docs:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

NoAttr is doing this to you:

> NoAttr => 1 # in+out - handy
>
> When used with XMLout(), the generated XML will contain no attributes. All hash key/values will be represented as nested elements instead.
>
> When used with XMLin(), any attributes in the XML will be ignored.

You *might* find that specifying `NoAttr` on the `XMLin` will do what you want?

However I would suggest instead - use [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml =
    '<language name="en_US" title="sprint" subtitle="" url="sprint/en_US/index.html" />';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parse($xml);

foreach my $key ( keys %{ $twig->root->atts() } ) {
    print "$key => ", $twig->root->att($key), "\n";
}

$twig->root->del_att('name');

print "With 'name' removed:\n";
$twig->root->print;
```

If you can give me a bit more of a sample of input/output to compare, I can flesh out this example a bit more. You probably don't want to be using `root` here, because that's only really for the 'top' element - but consider this illustrative. You can do a `foreach ( $twig -> root -> children ) {` type iteration.

Comment: Twig is the solution for me. => Thank you very much